While solving Wave equation using FDM, how to solve and related eigenvalues
$\ t>0, x\in (0,\pi)$

\begin{cases}
u_{tt}=u_{xx}\\
u(t,0) = u(t,\pi)=0\\
u(0,x)= exp(-32(x-(\pi/2))^2\\
u_t(0,x)=0
\end{cases}
We assume that sufficient smoothness in $u$  and using
\begin{cases}
u_t=p_x\\
p_t=u_x
\end{cases}
We want to solve this by second order centered FDM and want to prove that when
$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}& 0
\end{bmatrix}$ ,
then $A[u\ p ]^T =\lambda[u\ p]^T$ and the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is pure imaginary numbers.
How can I prove this? I have been considering hours but I have no clues.

Let $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ have purely imaginary eigenvalues $\{\lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_n\}$ and corresponding orthonormal eigenvectors $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$. Now consider $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & D \\ D & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. We then have
$$
\begin{aligned}
A\begin{pmatrix} v_i \\ v_i \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & D \\ D & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} v_i \\ v_i \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_i v_i \\ \lambda_i v_i \end{pmatrix} = \lambda_i \begin{pmatrix} v_i \\ v_i \end{pmatrix}  \\ \\
A\begin{pmatrix} v_i \\ -v_i \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & D \\ D & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} v_i \\ -v_i \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -\lambda_i v_i \\ \lambda_i v_i \end{pmatrix} = -\lambda_i \begin{pmatrix} v_i \\  -v_i. \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore, $\sigma(A) = \{\pm \lambda_1, \dots, \pm \lambda_n\}$ with eigenvectors described above. Note that even if the $\lambda_i$'s aren't distinct, we have still found a complete set of $2n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, so this set is the complete spectrum of $A$. Since $\lambda_i$'s were all purely imaginary, $\pm \lambda_i$ is as well and we are done.
Now to apply this result, all you have to show is that the centered difference approximation of the first derivative has purely imaginary eigenvalues, which is true since it is a real skew-symmetric matrix.
